# Cant setup auto refresh browser with play framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

i followed the steps outlined here:
https://github.com/jamesward/play-auto-refresh

I am not sure I added this plugin correctly.

What does ".. plugin bootstraps itself automatically as soon as you enable Play in your project." mean?

Thank you